# How do I change the order of the Views row fields programmatically?

Tags: 7, views, hooks

How do I change the order of the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) row fields (programmatically) not by Views UI?

E.g: the last field should come up first in the list.

Any hooks available?

**Note**:
I can not use the Views UI, as I don't own the code for feature re-create, so I'm looking for some hooks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go with one of Views API hooks, e.g: [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7)

You can access Views rows by `$views->result`.